# Proble making coordinates that are plotted onto an image that's loaded in a dialog box, accurate regardless of phone screen size in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, screen

In Flutter/Dart, I create a showdialog box and then, after a selection is made, I load a jpg which depicts a map.  Onto of that image layer in the dialog box, I use the trasnlate function to move and zoom the image to the appropriate location for a specific selection.  I then further, plot points onto a layer that is located on top of the image.  Accordingly, the dialog box takes up 70 percent of the main widget.  I'm having trouble making everything remain accurate when I use a screen size different that the one on which I plotted the coordinates (Samsung Galaxy S20 FE).  Below I'm providing the code that is being run, as well as example of the data from the global, in which the coordinates are supplied:

```
class TradeSelection extends StatelessWidget {
  //final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;
  final String tcIndexNum;

  //TradeSelection(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);
  TradeSelection(this.tcIndexNum, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
          foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
          textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
        ),
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();

/////////////////////////////////////////////
// MAP IMAGE LOADER
          final TransformationController _transformationController =
              TransformationController();

// pulls the screen sizes and then determines the offset
          double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

// pulls the index of the selected button by matching the name
// to the nodes list
          // int selectionIndex = tradeCardsList.values
          //     .map((tradeCard) => tradeCard['nodes'].indexOf(answerText))
          //     .firstWhere((index) => index >= 0, orElse: () => null);
          //ABOVE CODE PROVIDES ERRORS
          int selectionIndex =
              tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['nodes'].indexOf(answerText);

// If the index is not null, use it to retrieve the corresponding
// coordinates from the 'coords' list for the 't011' trade card
          if (selectionIndex != null) {
            double xPercent =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][0];
            double yPercent =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][1];
            double scalePercent =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][2];

// Calculates screensize offset based on the amount of translation
// as well as the size of the screen
            double xVal = xPercent;
            double yVal = yPercent;
            double scaleVal = scalePercent;

//Image Transform Controller
            _transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()
              // ..translate(xVal, yVal + 10)
              // USE THE (yVal + 10) WHEN LOADING TO THE REAL S20 FE
              ..translate(xVal, yVal)
              ..scale(scaleVal);

//Coordinates used for plotting the dots over the image
            double coordsX1 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][3];
            double coordsY1 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][4];
            double coordsX2 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][5];
            double coordsY2 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][6];
            double coordsX3 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][7];
            double coordsY3 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][8];
            double coordsX4 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][9];
            double coordsY4 =
                tradeCardsList[tcIndexNum]['coords'][selectionIndex][10];


    //Displays the map
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
                  side: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.brown[900],
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0), // essentially no border
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height:
                            screenHeight * 0.7, // adjust the height as needed
                        child: Stack(
                          fit: StackFit.expand,
                          children: [
                            InteractiveViewer(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              //aligns the image to the center
                              transformationController:
                                  _transformationController,
                              child: Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/eutpop1444.jpg',
                                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              ),
                              maxScale: 4.0,
                              minScale: 0.5,
                              boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(200),
                              constrained: true,
                              alignPanAxis: true,
                              panEnabled: true,
                              scaleEnabled: true,
                              onInteractionEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
                                // do something when the interaction ends
                              },
                            ),

                          
                            DotOverlay(x: coordsX2, y: coordsY2),
                            DotOverlay(x: coordsX3, y: coordsY3),
                            DotOverlay(x: coordsX4, y: coordsY4),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ), 


    GLOBAL LIST DATA EXAMPLE:  

      'LocationCardID1': {
    'nodes': ['Location 1', 'Location 2', 'Location 3'],
    'coords': [
      [
        1559.697, //xPercent
        176.248, //yPercent
        14.00, //scalePercent
        40.00, //x1
        197.00, //y1
        149.00, //x2
        235.00, //y2
        149.00, //x3
        235.00, //y3
        197.00, //x4
        302.00 //y4
      ],
      [
        1765.00, //xPercent
        -770.00, //yPercent
        15.627, //scalePercent
        45.00, //x1
        265.00, //y1
        99.00, //x2
        309.00, //y2
        45.00, //x3
        265.00, //y3
        45.00, //x4
        265.00 //y4
      ],
      [
        948.611, //xPercent
        -21.704, //yPercent
        9.00, //scalePercent
        240.00, //x1
        125.00, //y1
        188.00, //x2
        215.00, //y2
        240.00, //x3
        125.00, //y3
        217.00, //x4
        185.00 //y4
      ],
      ],
      },
```

I've tried using media query to get the screen size and then making some offsets based on the difference between the current screen size the the S20 fe screen size but I'm doing something wrong and am not sure what is the best way to use the captured data to make the appropriate adjustments to all of the coordinates so that they remain accurate, regardless of the screen size.  Does anyone have any suggestions/recommendations?